# Get count if column value does not exist in another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following two queries:

```
select count(*) from table_1 where c_id=12345

select count(*) from table_2 where success=1 and c_id=12345
```

I add these two counts on the C# layer.  However, `table_1` and `table_2` both have a column called `m_id`.  I want to be able to get the total count where `table_2` has both these conditions:

- `success=1 and c_id=12345`
- and `m_id` does not equal any `m_id` from `table_1 where c_id=12345`.

Is this possible to do?  Is it possible to do it in a single query? I'm still new to SQL, so I apologize if this an obvious question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a `not exists` clause to the second query:

```
select count(*)
from table_2 t2
where t2.success = 1 and t2.c_id = 12345 and
      not exists (select 1 from table_1 t1 where t1.m_id = t2.mid and t1.c_id = 12345);
```

Comment: I'm assuming this `and c_id = 12345)` should be `and t1.c_id = 12345)` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`NOT EXISTS`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188336.aspx):

```
select
    count(*)
from table_2
where success = 1
    and c_id = 12345
    and not exists
    (
        select 
            1 
        from table_1 
        where table_2.m_id = table_1.m_id and table_1.c_id = 12345
    )
```